# Flutter MapBox navigation generated APK issue

Tags: android, flutter

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_mapbox_navigation:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:/Users/prometteur/Downloads/route_record/build/flutter_mapbox_navigation/intermediates/merged_res/release/layout/navigation_activity.xml:2: AAPT: error: resource string/mapbox_access_token (aka eopeter.flutter_mapbox_navigation:string/mapbox_access_token) not found.
```

I want to know the app is run proper but when i build apk so its show error